# Jquery UI Draggable not working - ui-draggable added but no drag event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable

I am using

```
$('.swipeenabled').draggable({ axis: "x"})
```

for getting x-draggable feature.

I have the following order of js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "crsq/js/zippednewsapp/jquery-1.10.2.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "crsq/js/zippednewsapp/bootstrap.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "crsq/js/zippednewsapp/jail.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "crsq/js/zippednewsapp/jquery-ui.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "crsq/js/zippednewsapp/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js" %}"></script>
```

We know that draggable is working, since ui-draggable class gets added to the elements .swipeenabled

But, the dragging feature does not work. What are the possible reasons? The jquery and jquery-ui js files are not corrupt. I have checked that.

Comment: I guess some problem with jquery files and its order

Comment: Have you tried creating a barebone example with only the required javascript? If the stripped down example works you may have conflicts with other scripts.

Comment: A simple demo works here: http://jsfiddle.net/GSpdW/1/; can you provide more context? Your HTML code? Any errors in the console and network?

Comment: When I remove the other js files, it still does not work. So, there is no issue of conflict. The order is jquery and then jquery-ui. So, that should also be fine. What else can be the issue?

Comment: When I use google cdn jquery and jquery-ui libraries. Still nothing. No error. Its being executed for sure, because ui-draggable class gets added

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward no error on console. no error on network.

Comment: @PratikPoddar provide your HTML markup or a demo on jsfiddle

Comment: Please open mobile user agent and check it out please. http://www.zippednews.com/evernote 
Note that .swipeenabled has .ui-draggable in it.

Comment: @PratikPoddar I see what is the purpose of being draggable? I see is working fine with swipe feature

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward In between swipe and touch, a drag feature would give user response that your input is being taken. Better UI.

Comment: Got the solution. Its the same as:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940421/how-to-get-jqueryui-drag-drop-working-with-touch-devices

Answer (score 0):

you need to load the jQuery library before jQuery UI:

For example below code works:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   $('.swipeenabled').draggable({ axis: "x"})       });
</script>
<body>
  <div class="swipeenabled">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
  </div>
```

DEMO:-

http://jsfiddle.net/u7zWA/395/

Comment: From the code provided it seems to be loaded before

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940421/how-to-get-jqueryui-drag-drop-working-with-touch-devices is the solution.