# Is there a solution to introduce both drag and scroll on mobile devices using?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, jquery-ui-touch-punch

Is there a solution to introduce both drag and scroll on mobile devices using Jquery UI and Jquery ui touch punch?

[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twje6.gif)
I have added image which will explain use case.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  Can you reword the question? What specifically are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might be a duplicate of this [How to get jQueryUI drag\drop working with touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940421/how-to-get-jqueryui-drag-drop-working-with-touch-devices)

There are some workarounds that require constantly reading and storing touch events like `touchmove`, but for the most party there are easier ways