# List items are not draggable in touch screen browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created a puzzle game with [image-puzzle-js](https://github.com/softgandhi/image-puzzle-js)  library but the `<li>` items do not drag in mobile browsers.

I tried jQuery draggable instead of draggable:true css

```
        $(li).draggable({
            snap: '#droppable',
            snapMode: 'outer',
            revert: "invalid",
            helper: "clone"
        });
```

but its not working as expecting

I tried the following with touch punch, but still the issue occurs

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
$('li').draggable();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get jQueryUI drag\drop working with touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940421/how-to-get-jqueryui-drag-drop-working-with-touch-devices)

Comment: I tried it, but that doesnt seems to solve the problem

Comment: Try https://hammerjs.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing all of your code (the html and the javascript) you have makes this more difficult but...

From your example above:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
$('li').draggable();
```

`$('li').draggable();` is not doing anything where you have it now (except possibly displaying on the page.  For it to work, it needs to be in a script tag and most likely needs to be set to run once your document has fully loaded.

Try changing to something like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('li').draggable();
    });
</script>
```

That should tell your page to make your `<li>` elements draggable once the page is fully loaded.

Once you get that working start to learn about where in your page the script tags should go (In `<head>`, bottom of `<body>`, etc), when to use `$(document).ready()` with jQuery and how to use your browser's developer console to see what's happening as the page loads.